# MONGODB find inside a document collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb so I'm having a little issue right here

I have a collection that looks like this..

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "5f7a1b6a3aedab1df33574bb",
    "name": "myFirstGame",
    "players": [
      {
        "_id": "5f7a1be79acaf41e058ccd9f",
        "name": "Albert",
        "points": 10
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f7a20de87f0fc1ea309145c",
        "name": "Adam",
        "points": 10
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f7a25fdcd01211fc84afd0e",
        "name": "John",
        "points": 10
      }
    ],
    "description": "This is a fun game to watch",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to get the players which name is 'John'

So, what I'm actually doing is:

```js
try{
        const cond = {
          _id: '5f7a1b6a3aedab1df33574bb', //the id of the game
          'players.name': { $eq: 'John' }, // the condition on the player
        }
        player = await Game.find(cond, 'players');
        return player;
}catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

What I'm expecting to get is an object like this

```json
      {
        "_id": "5f7a25fdcd01211fc84afd0e",
        "name": "John",
        "points": 10
      }
```

But I'm getting the full object of the game, without any filter

```
          'players.name': { $eq: 'John' }, // the condition on the player
```

in this field right here I already tried things like

```
players: {name: 'John'} // this returns me an empty array
players.name: 'John'
```

I can do this filtering with NodeJS but I think it might be a way to solve this with mongo,

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `cond` passed the _id of the game (`_id: '5f7a1b6a3aedab1df33574bb'`) as an argument to `Game.find()`, which is why it returned the entire game.

Have you tried querying directly, like:
`db.Games.find( { name: "John" } )` or `player = await Game.find({name: "John"});` ?

Comment: Yes! I did this too.. the thing is that I want to filter a game too.. it's for a REST api

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation plays action.

1. `$filter` helps to find the specific object in an array
2. `$unwind` to flat the array
3. `$replaceRoot` to replace the object to the root

Mongo script

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      players: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$players",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.name",
              "John"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$players"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$players"
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/85xEwIMFA39)**